# Implementing Label Encoder as a Tensorflow Preprocessing layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

From my understanding from SKLearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), `LabelEncoder` in SKLearn encodes values between 0 and the number of classes subtracted by 1 (i.e. `n_classes` - 1).

I wanted to use something similar as a part of a Tensorflow preprocessing operation to avoid using SKLearn for a package. For example, I understand the preprocessing layer provides APIs for OneHot encoding and Categorical Encoding easily as follows:

```
tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
    num_tokens=None, output_mode='multi_hot', sparse=False, **kwargs
)
```

Is there any way to use LabelEncoder by certain arguments in the `CategoryEncoding` API, or do I have to define a brand new pre-processing layer using the [abstract base class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/PreprocessingLayer) template provided in the Tensorflow documentations?

If so, is there any possible reference on how I can write my own class for using `LabelEncoder` as a Tensorflow layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you just need sparse integer labels. So, maybe try something simple and naive first:

```
classes = ['fish1', 'fish2', 'fish3']

data = ['fish1', 'fish2', 'fish3', 'fish2', 'fish3', 'fish1']

class_indices = dict(zip(classes, range(len(classes))))
labels = list(map(class_indices.get, data))

print(labels)
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]
```

Or with `Tensorflow`, you can use `StaticHashTable`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

classes = ['fish1', 'fish2', 'fish3']
data = tf.constant(['fish1', 'fish2', 'fish3', 'fish2', 'fish3', 'fish1'])

table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf.constant(classes), tf.range(len(classes))),
    default_value=-1)

label_encoder = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: table.lookup(x))

print(label_encoder(data))
```

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 1 2 0], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)
```